# Router shows 'page not available' when browsing to stackoverflow.com

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I have this weird situation going on. When I browse to http://www.stackoverflow.com or any sister related site (like this one, superuser.com) I get 'Page not available'.

All my computers that are connected with my router in my network can't access those websites.

Here's my setup: I have one modem and a router. The WLAN port of the modem is connected to the WLAN port of my router.

What I think is that somehow my router isn't routing those sites. Bacause when I connect my laptop directly to the modem, so I cut out my router, I can access stackoverflow.com.

When the router is connected to the modem, and I go to the adin page of my router, I can ping or trace stackoverflow.com from my router with success. So my router itself is able to connect to those sites.

I've tried to power off the router and the modem, then power on the modem (wait a little bit), then power on the router (wait a little bit) and then surf the internet. Sometimes it works and I can access SO.com, but sometimes it doesn't. And when it works, later on, it doesn't work anymore (usually the next morning).

In the situation when I can't access SO (that's most of the time) I can access it when I use a proxy like hidemyass.com.

Does someone has any idea what's going on here?

BTW I have a TP-Link router model TL-WR941ND and internet through cable (not adsl)

UPDATE:
results of command:

nslookup stackoverflow.com: Server: unknown, Address: 192.168.0.1
tracert stackoverflow.com: UNable to resolve target system name stackoverflow.com

The same results when prefisinf it with www.

Comment: Show output of commands `nslookup stackoverflow.com` and `tracert stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is a problem with dns. Change your dns address to google dns - 8.8.8.8 or OpenDNS - 208.67.222.222.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working right now. I'm curious if it still does tomorrow...I've used Google for primary DNS and OpenDns as my secondary